# A "Commands" element appeared in my Unity launcher...what is it?

Tags: unity, launcher, lenses

As you can see, this blank Commands lens is now on my Unity Launcher, without installing any related software. It launches the *Run a command* dialog (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) but it has no icon...how did it get there? Is it related to recent Unity updates? Or maybe to some application? If so, how can I get rid of it, since there's no file under `/usr/share/unity/places`? Thanks for your time!

[image: The mysterious Commands lens]

Comment: Can you check if you have a mangled file somewhere in /usr/share/unity/places?

Comment: No files whatsoever there, aisde from applications.place and files.place. By the way, I just found out that the ghost lens can be replaced above or below the other lenses, but not above the worskpace switcher nor the launchers.

Comment: I showed this problem to some unity devs and they've never seen this before, if you could file a bug on this problem it would be great: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

What it is, is a bug. File a report on launchpad.net and gain some Karma. Attach that screenshot. :)

As for how you get rid of it, if you press alt+f2 and run compiz --replace, then I'm fairly sure it'll go away.

As a wild guess, I'd say "Commands" is the default label for launcher quicklists and that somehow, an empty and unconfigured launcher entry has been created for some reason. But it's a wild guess and it might very well be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar. I tried to add a launchericon to the launcher, which was executing the xkill command. It worked but instead of a symbol there was a blank space, however by rightclicking and clicking keep in the launcher I could remover this issue.

Comment: I should have showed it in the picture, but there isn't any option nor quicklist when right clicking the "ghost" icon. There' s just a Commands options which launches the dialog exactly the same way as a left-click does.